# <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/> shows invalid xpath in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt, group-by, xslt-3.0

What is the error in this xslt? It says invalid xpath in line <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/> though it working fine when I use xslt version 2.0 (no streaming).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="BlockSize" as="xs:integer" select="2000"/>
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
   
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="root/wd:Get_Workers_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker" group-adjacent="floor((position() -1) div $BlockSize)">
                <group>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>     <-- ERROR - Invalid Xpath
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>            
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am trying to group a list of workers in xml into a few groups of 2000 workers each.

Comment: Which XSLT processor exactly is that, which version and edtion of the processor exactly?

Comment: I am using it in Workday Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with configuration. Disabling the xsl validator (window > preferences > validation) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon 9.7 (as well as later releases) accept this stylesheet with no problems.

I strongly suspect that you have not configured Workday correctly to run XSLT 2.0.

To verify this, try running a simple stylesheet (one that works under XSLT 1.0, but specifying version="2.0" in case that affects the choice of processor), outputting the value of `system-property('xsl:vendor')` and `system-property('xsl:version')`.

Also, please quote the exact error message rather than paraphrasing it. The exact wording of an error message is often a clue that indicates what XSLT processor you are running.